# How separate are C# and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, programming-languages

I see language features like C#'s `foreach` loop (which requires the use of `IEnumerable`), and its `using` syntax (which uses `IDisposable`, knowing which method to call), and LINQ (which I assume uses a heap of .NET stuff too). All of this seems very tied-in to the .NET framework. So:

- Could C# exist with a different framework? (Does it already?)
- If so, how does a language specify "foreach loops require an IEnumerable instance" without tying it in to a framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best place to investigate this is the [C# language specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=188622).
For example, in the case of enumerables, here are some snippets from the spec:

> **10.14.2 Enumerable interfaces**
>
> The enumerable interfaces are the
> non-generic interface
> System.Collections.IEnumerable and all
> instantiations of the generic
> interface
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.
> For the sake of brevity, in this
> chapter these interfaces are
> referenced as IEnumerable and
> IEnumerable, respectively.
>
> ...
>
> **10.14.5.1 The GetEnumerator method**
>
> An enumerable object provides an
> implementation of the GetEnumerator
> methods of the IEnumerable and
> IEnumerable interfaces. The two
> GetEnumerator methods share a common
> implementation that acquires and
> returns an available enumerator
> object. The enumerator object is
> initialized with the argument values
> and instance value saved when the
> enumerable object was initialized, but
> otherwise the enumerator object
> functions as described in §10.14.4.

This ties in nicely with how these interfaces are *actually* defined in the .NET BCL, although it would be completely possible for a different (i.e. non-.NET) framework to provide a similar, compatible implementation that a C# compiler could then target.

Portions of the spec that are hard to separate from the .NET framework are normally marked with:

> Note: This section is applicable only to the Microsoft .NET implementation of C#.

On another note,`foreach`doesn't actually *require*`IEnumerable`; it can use a sort of 'duck-typing', which you can read about in section 8.8.4 of the spec.

Comment: Ah, so it's really all about the *implementation* of the language, then?

Comment: @Smashery: I think it's better to think of it in terms of the implementation of a compliant *compiler*.

Comment: As an aside, LINQ *syntax* doesn't place any specific demands either; like `foreach`, it is entirely pattern-based. Expression trees are more dependent, but the details of this translation is actually not in the spec anyway.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes - [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is an open source
   cross-platform implementation of the
   .Net framework.
2. Not sure, good
   question.  Mono replaces both the
   .Net framework *and* the CLR, and so
   this is not a problem for Mono.

Comment: True, although, as you say, Mono is an implementation of the .NET framework. It's not really a different framework. I'm more wondering along the lines of "Could C# work with something so different as the Python library?"